# From longitude and latitude to cell number

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
 LonSHIP  LatSHIP LonINT LatINT
 -179.94  -38.05      1    128
 -179.93  -32.54      1    123
 -179.93  -32.19      1    122
 -179.93  -31.83      1    122
 -179.92  -33.97      1    124
 -179.92  -33.61      1    124
```

What I want is to associate at each (ordered) pair (LonINT,LatINT) a number to identify the grid cell.

E.g.

```
 LonSHIP  LatSHIP LonINT LatINT cell
 -179.94  -38.05      1    128   1
 -179.93  -32.54      1    123   2
 -179.93  -32.19      1    122   3
 -179.93  -31.83      1    122   3
 -179.92  -33.97      1    124   4
 -179.92  -33.61      1    124   4
```

Note that, for example

(1, 2) != (2,1), i.e. they must have two different cell number.

Can anyone help?

Comment: To complete a reproducible example, add the desired output to your question.

Comment: How are the cells decided? Does it depend on the limits of the data (range of Lon and Lat) or it is a domain-specific predefined term?

Comment: @AdityaJoshi the cell number it's just a label, doesn't matter

Comment: Try `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, cell := .GRP, by = list(LonINT, LatINT)]` (if your data set called `df`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ordered pairs then you need first to order by multiple columns:

```
dat<-dat[order(dat$LonINT,dat$LatINT,decreasing=F),]
```

Then you can use a simple formula to concatenate the two values. For example, if `max(LatINT)<1000` you can do:

```
gridINT=dat$LonINT*1000+dat$LatINT
```

EDIT: Well, actually the first order is not needed with this formula because the ordering following the new `gridINT` identifier should give the same result.